# Query to fetch table names from AX takes too long

Tags: axapta, x++

I am using the following code in X++ to get table names:

```
client server public static container tableNames()
{
tableId         tableId;
int             tablecounter;
Dictionary      dict = new Dictionary();
container       tableNamesList;

for (tablecounter=1; tablecounter<=dict.tableCnt(); tablecounter++)
{
    tableId = dict.tableCnt2Id(tablecounter);
    tableNamesList = conIns(tableNamesList,1,dict.tableName(tableId));
}

return tableNamesList;
}
```

Business connector code :

```
tablesList = (AxaptaContainer)Global.ax.
                CallStaticClassMethod("Code_Generator", "tableNames");

for (int i = 1; i <= tablesList.Count; i++)
{
    tableName = tablesList.get_Item(i).ToString();
    tables.Add(tableName);
}
```

The application hangs for 2 - 3 minutes while fetching data. What could be the cause? Any optimizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have tried a lot of things and in the end, I decided to create a table consisting of all table names. This table will have a Job populating it. I am fetching records from this table.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use ConIns, use +=, it will be faster

```
tableNamesList += dict.tableName(tableId);
```

ConIns has to work out where in the container to place the insert. += just adds it to the end

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it still hangs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before avoid conIns() when appending elements to a container because it makes a new copy of the container. Use += instead to append in place.

Also, you may want to check for permissions and leave out temporary tables, table maps, and other special cases. Standard Ax has a method to build a table name lookup form that takes these things into account. Check the method Global::pickTable() for details.

You could avoid some calls through the business connector as well and build the entire list in Ax in a similar way and return that in a single function call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dynamics Ax 2012, you could skip the treeNode stuff and use the SysModelElement table to fetch the data and return it immediately as a .Net Array to easy up things on the other side.

```
public static System.Collections.ArrayList FetchTableNames_ModelElementTables()
{
    SysModelElement                 element;
    SysModelElementType             elementType;
    System.Collections.ArrayList    tableNames = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    ;  

    // The SysModelElementType table contains the element types 
    // and we need the recId for the next selection
    select firstonly RecId
    from  elementType
    where elementType.Name == 'Table';

    // With the recId of the table element type, 
    // select all of the elements with that type (hence, select all of the tables)
    while select Name
        from element
        where element.ElementType == elementType.RecId
    {
        tableNames.Add(element.Name);
    }

    return tableNames;
    }
}
```